# Corrupt .resources file. Got an unexpected EndOfStreamException while trying to read the ResourceReader header

Tags: file, header, resources

plz help me to fix this Exception :

```
Corrupt .resources file. Got an unexpected EndOfStreamException while trying to read the ResourceReader header.
```

I was checked it out 
and it is ok

I am using C# - VB.Net 2008

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to clear the project solution by the following steps

**1: from the main menu click on -> Build 
2: click on Clean solutions
3: click on Clean 'ProjectName' 
3: Then finally Re-build your project**

That is all , hope to be this is the solution it is working I tried it before